# How to make an object fit in a unit cube?

Tags: export, vertex-groups

In my blender object, there are hundreds of vertices, normals, faces and etc and the thing I want to do is to make it fit in a unit cube. I've tried almost everything including

1. Trying to find an option in *file->export.*
2. Selecting all the things using <kbd>A</kbd> button,
       assigning into one vertex group and
       pushing *normalize all* button in "Weight tools" pane.
3. Scaling the object somehow.

   None of them works. So I need a little help. Please show me the way how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain more, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to scale the object, or morph the object into a cube shape?

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do right now is to scale the object in a unit cube. AFAIK, to use hundreds of wavefront obj in OpenGL, every vertices in every object should be within range of 0 to 1 to use them efficiently when it comes to managing all the objects. So I want to make every vertex within range of 0 to 1

Comment: Respecting the overall proportions, or fitting to the unit cube ?

Comment: Respecting the overall proportions.

Comment: Is that 1 object (with hundred of vertices, etc), or several objects ?

Comment: Every obj file has only one object. So 1 object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of script (works with the active object) :

[image]

Alternative script, so that :

- Rotation and scale are previously applied (avoid border effects when export)
- Place all the vertices between 0 and 1 (previous script only matters about overall dimensions)

[image]

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.object

#Eventually apply transforms (comment if unwanted)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply( rotation = True, scale = True )

minX = min( [vertex.co[0] for vertex in obj.data.vertices] )
minY = min( [vertex.co[1] for vertex in obj.data.vertices] )
minZ = min( [vertex.co[2] for vertex in obj.data.vertices] )

vMin = Vector( [minX, minY, minZ] )

maxDim = max(obj.dimensions)

if maxDim != 0:
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        v.co -= vMin #Set all coordinates start from (0, 0, 0)
        v.co /= maxDim #Set all coordinates between 0 and 1
else:
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        v.co -= vMin
```

Comment: This is exactly one I was looking for!!!

Comment: @Windforces, note that the vertices coordinates wont be between 0 and 1 here. Just the size is scaled down to 1 (like in Todd answer). So tell if it is ok.

Comment: @Windforces, edited in case of need (added a more complete script)

Answer (score 0):

Just scale the object down until 2 of the scale coordinates are less than 1.0, and the third is equal to 1.0. Simple enough unless I don't understand the question properly.

[image]

Comment: Guess this would be a simple answer for my question

Comment: Do you need to do this many times? Perhaps a python script would make it easier?

Comment: I'll try to make the python script. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Windforces, Todd, sorry, I did not saw that before posting